# GEO_DISTANCE search in view returns nothing, even though ANALYZER returns true

Tags: arangodb, aql

I'm trying to perform a [geospatial search](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/index-and-search/arangosearch/geospatial-search/) in ArangoDB and even though the analyzer returns `true`, the search results are empty.

The query attempts to find all users who are within range (`distanceMeters`) of this user:

```
FOR user IN users
  FILTER user._key == 'c8a8d416-a0c2-4cc4-b583-ad0a8bfb3389'
  LET userLocation = GEO_POINT(user.location[0], user.location[1])
  LET distanceMeters = 100 * 1609
  
  FOR targetUser IN UserSearch
    SEARCH ANALYZER(GEO_DISTANCE(userLocation, targetUser.location) < distanceMeters, "geoPair")
    LET analysis = ANALYZER(GEO_DISTANCE(userLocation, targetUser.location) <= distanceMeters, "geoPair")
    LET distance = ROUND(GEO_DISTANCE(targetUser.location, user.location))
    
    SORT distance
    LIMIT 10
    
    RETURN {
        analysis,
        distance,
        userLocation: user.location,
        targetLocation: targetUser.location,
    }
```

This returns an empty array

```json
[]
```

If I comment out the `SEARCH` line, it returns results with the analysis attribute set to true:

```json
[
  { "analysis":true, "distance":0, "userLocation":[37.80435,-122.271164], "targetLocation":[44.05207,-123.086754] },
  { "analysis":true, "distance":0, "userLocation":[37.80435,-122.271164], "targetLocation":[34.151783,-118.45889] },
  { "analysis":true, "distance":0, "userLocation":[37.80435,-122.271164], "targetLocation":[37.33874,-121.885254] }
]
```

### Additional Details

ArangoDB version: 3.11.4

The `UserSearch` view definition:

```json
{
  "writebufferSizeMax": 33554432,
  "id": "9348168",
  "storedValues": [],
  "name": "UserSearch",
  "type": "arangosearch",
  "consolidationPolicy": {
    "type": "tier",
    "segmentsBytesFloor": 2097152,
    "segmentsBytesMax": 5368709120,
    "segmentsMax": 10,
    "segmentsMin": 1,
    "minScore": 0
  },
  "writebufferActive": 0,
  "links": {
    "users": {
      "analyzers": [
        "identity"
      ],
      "fields": {
        "location": {
          "analyzers": [
            "geoPair"
          ]
        }
      },
      "includeAllFields": true,
      "storeValues": "none",
      "trackListPositions": false
    }
  },
  "commitIntervalMsec": 1000,
  "consolidationIntervalMsec": 1000,
  "globallyUniqueId": "h6E0356583726/9348168",
  "cleanupIntervalStep": 2,
  "primarySort": [],
  "primarySortCompression": "lz4",
  "writebufferIdle": 64
}
```

An example of a user document:

```json
{
  "birthday": 348278400000,
  "gender": "man",
  "name": "Jeremy",
  "lastActive": 1698800214523,
  "location": [
    37.80435,
    -122.271164
  ]
}
```